# How to scale an SVG drawing

Tags: javascript, html, svg, photoshop

If I have a map in SVG format, how can I scale the image to be say, X times bigger? How would I achieve this? I want to be able to scale it based on an X variable which of course varies

I have looked into it but I am stretched for time. I just want to know where to begin.

Comment: what have you done so for *post your code*

Answer (score 1):

To scale SVG data you need to use a [scale transformation.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform)

So to make an element, e.g 3 times bigger you would use:

```
var mySVG = document.getElementById("mySvgElement");
var scaleCoefficient = 3; //this will make it 3 times bigger in x/y direction
mySVG.setAttribute("transform", "scale(" + scaleCoefficient + "," + scaleCoefficient + ")");
```

That will apply a scale transformation of '3' in *x/y* directions thus making the element 3 times bigger without changing it's aspect ratio

SVG elements are defined by a [transformation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix) - this is what vector shapes generally use to define translation/rotation/size without changing the actual SVG geometry data of the shapes themselves.

Comment: I would also suggest doing the transformation to a `<g>` tag that encapsulates your svg drawing.